# Extract a numerical value from a file in java

Tags: java, file, integer, substring, extract

My file (rates.txt) contains: `Abc defghijk lmn opqr st uvwxyza bc 19`

I want to extract only the `19` from the file and store it as an integer.

How do I go about this?

I've tried using a substring but am unsure what method to use in order to make it select only the numerical value.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer is also going to depend on the consistency of your data. Is the numeric data always going to be at the end? Is there always going to be a single numeric token, while all others are alpha? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: It's just this single piece of data, all I want to do is import the data and take out the number 19 so I can then use it in the programme.

Answer (score 3):

What if you use a regular expression. 
Try this (I assumed you only have one integer value):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Tester {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d+)\\D*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Abc defghijk lmn opqr st uvwxyza bc 19");

    try {
        if (matcher.find()) {
          String stringDigit = matcher.group(1);
          int number = Integer.parseInt(stringDigit);
          System.out.println(number);

        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
  }

}
```

The pattern "\D*(\d+)\D*" actually means:

\D*: multiple non-digit characters (including zero amount of character)

\d+: multiple digit characters

So, we are searching some digit characters enclosed by some non-digit characters.

```
Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d+)\\D*");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "xAbc defghijk lmn opqr st uvwxyza bc 19";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            int number = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("First number: "+number);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't as useful as ones which include an explanation of what the code is doing. "Teach a man to fish," and all that.

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through each line within the file.
- To do so you can use Iterator and its method hasNext()
- Once you've retrieved a line, split it by the empty spaces as follows:

  > String str = "";
  >
  > List< String> splitElements = Arrays.asList(str.split("\s+"));
- Afterwards, loop through each element of the list and it'd be a good idea to create a helperMethod in charge of verifying whether an element is number or not. It could be achieved with something like this:

  public static boolean isNumeric(String string) {
    try
    {
      int intString = Integer.parseInt(string);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
- Make notice that it parses just **int** numbers, create more helper methods and you're done, hope it helps!